# Setting up Cookiecutter in Python

Tags: python-2.7, templates, cookiecutter

I have used the following code for Cookiecutter set up:

step 1:
`conda install cookicutter` (this worked by installing all packages)

step 2 :
`$ cookiecutter https://github.com/drivendata/cookiecutter-data-science` (this doesn't execute)
it gives me `bash: cookiecutter: command not found`

I have taken this code from one of courses for Data science and the code works fine there, But I am unable to run from my end. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwEpG.png)

Comment: In step 1, you write `conda install cookicutter`. I assume this is a typo? Anyway, this might be why the command is not found.

Answer (score 0):

cookiecutter might not be on the path

Check with

`which cookiecutter`

`locate cookiecutter`

Then add to path